# Why can classes be used as type parameters and what for?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've accidentally discovered that the following is a perfectly compiling code:

```
class SomeClass a

someValue :: Maybe (SomeClass a)
someValue = undefined
```

I'm only used to seeing classes in type constraints, so I don't understand why this code typechecks and what's the purpose of using classes that way.

I'm on GHC 7.6.2.

Comment: Do you have any GHC extensions turned on? With constraint kinds enabled I expect you'd get a kind mismatch, i.e. `Maybe :: * -> *` vs `SomeClass :: * -> Constraint`. Classes and types share the same namespace if memory serves me, and that's a kind error at best, so I'm not sure why it would be accepted by the compiler.

Comment: @C.A.McCann No. None. Just a plain `runghc` of a file with the contents as in the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you replace `undefined` with `Nothing`?

Comment: @C.A.McCann Still compiles

Comment: How about `Just undefined`?

Comment: @C.A.McCann Compiles too

Comment: Wow. Ok, that is hella weird and definitely needs to be reported.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a bug in ghc-7.6.2.  It should be a kind error.  Please report it.

Comment: Turns out to be already fixed: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7825#comment:1

Answer (score 3):

Error.

> A.hs:3:21:
>       Class `SomeClass' used as a type
>
> ```
> In the type signature for `someValue':
> ```

Comment: Forgot to mention. I'm on GHC 7.6.2